# Is there any way to escape the h:outputText tag's encoding for a particular character?

Tags: jsf

h:outputText tag converts the special character ê into & ecirc; which throws a xml parsing error. Is there any way I can make it encode ê into & #234;?

Comment: the code i have in my jsp is something like this
<h:outputText value="ê" styleClass="checkbox">

Comment: What JSF impl/version? What JSP version?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<h:outputText value="&#234;" escape="false" />
```